variable not defined in developer tools console
I have been using the console to examine variables but it has stopped working for me and I do not know why.
To illustrate the problem I have the following files which run locally on Apache so I access it at localhost/path/to/index.html.
index.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="module" src="./javascript/main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>...</h1>
</body>
</html>

main.js:

console.log("from main.js");
let sillyName = { number: 7 };

In Firefox and Chrome developer tools console if I start typing "sillyName" I would expect it to autocomplete to "sillyName" and show the value of that variable but I get an error as seen in this screenshot:

Obviously I am doing something differently to what I normally do but I can not work out what. Any help would be appreciated.

Unlike classic scripts, module scripts require the use of the CORS protocol for cross-origin fetching..

@LMC  That is not the point. Since they got the message from main.js, that means that they did what it takes for CORS (for example, not just loading local file index.html, but put it on a server along main.js). Answer has been given: modules have each their own context, which is not the one of the console.

@chrsig Other javascript websites I have work in this way. Not exactly sure what you mean by context?

@user3425506 The context is the environment in which the script is running. In modules, the context is always brand new and unattached to the document/window. Yet, both document and window are still available inside the module because they're defined in the module's global context (which is globalThis). In common scripts (which are not modules) the context of the document/window will be reused because everything is attached to the window object. This means that a variable defined in one common script will be available to the other. The same does not happen between modules.

@KLASANGUI thanks! Unfortunately I do not understand that but I am working on it. I am currently trying to simplify a website where it is working for me.  To my mind it is very similar but more complicated than the site I showed where it is not working. Both employ modules in exactly the same way(?) but obviously there is a difference.

@KLASANGUI I have just realized that the website where it is working has declared variables like this window.myVar. Where it has not been working I was using const myVar. When I change it the window.myVar form it works as before. Hopefully there are not bad sides to using the window object like that. Your explanation makes more sense to me now.

@KLASANGUI After I submitted my last comment I say your answer! I will read it now...

@user3425506 Let me say it like this... Each common script have the current window object as it's global context. Which means "var something = 1;" is the same as window.something = 1;. But modules are different. Each <script type="module"> will have an exclusive globalThis and a private context to store variables in a way that globalThis is not shared between different <script type="module"> tags. But globalThis is still shared inside the same <script type="module"> tag, meaning that a module imported into another with a import statement will share the same globalThis.

@user3425506 In both cases, window and document should reference to the current window/document element in the same way regardless if common script or module (unless if replaced with new definitions).

The problem is that sillyName is defined in a ESModule which have its own context.
To make sillyName available in the console, you should define the variable in the available window global object available in the module context:
// file: main.js
window.sillyName = { number: 7 };

Also, I recommend using the mjs extension: main.mjs.
<script type="module" src="main.mjs"></script>

// file: main.mjs
import { myFunction } from 'modules/some/module.mjs';

// Export something to other modules:
export const something = myFunction();

// Export something to CommonJS if in browser:
// window.something = something;

// Or like this that works even on back-ends:
(typeof window == 'object') && ( window.something = something );

// Export more stuff from another module:
export { someClass, anotherClass } from 'modules/another/module.mjs';

If you change the type attribute of the <script> to text/javascript then the sillyName will be automatically attached to the current window object but the script will no longer be a module.
The following guide should be very useful to understand the problem:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules
From the above guide:

Last but not least, let's make this clear — module features are imported into the scope of a single script — they aren't available in the global scope. Therefore, you will only be able to access imported features in the script they are imported into, and you won't be able to access them from the JavaScript console, for example. You'll still get syntax errors shown in the DevTools, but you'll not be able to use some of the debugging techniques you might have expected to use.


The problem now is that if I put an import statement at the top of the main.mjs file such as, import { dumbStuff } from "./modules/dumb-stuff.mjs";, I now get the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

I guess that is because changing the value of type from module to text/javascript means that main.(m)js is no longer considered to be a module so main can not import another module. I wonder if there is any way around this. I wanted to have a main module into which a number of "subsidiary" modules are imported. Perhaps that is not a great idea or perhaps I have to forgo having variables available to me in the console and use console.log when I need to inspect them.

@user3425506 Make sure that the <script> tag that loads main.mjs has the type="module" attribute. Also, the import statement should be at top-level, which means it should not be inside a block ({}) of any type (no if/try/function/etc...);

... or thirdly I could just use window.myVar but then I guess I lose the let / const distinction. (sorry about the rambling...)

just seen your comment.... But you said change the type of <script> to text/javascript?? I have put the import statement(s) at the top of the file not in any block. I will try reverting type to module

reverting type value to module got rid of the error about import statements at the top of the file but now let / const myVar not recognized.

@user3425506 I said "if you change", but my bad, I forgot to tell that the script will no longer be a module (I just edited my answer to fix that). You should stick with modules that are always better in my opinion. And if you want to expose something to the common context (which includes the html document) just do it through the current window global object like in the new example I added.

That sounds like a good plan!
